# How to concatenate SoX commands?

Tags: sox

I have this two commands in [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/):

```
  rec -V3 output.wav trim 0 50 
  sox output.wav out.wav trim 0 10 : newfile : restart
```

I need to do this work but in only one command line.

I need the recorded file "output.wav" to be trimmed into several files of 10 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them via a pipe, like this:

```
rec -p trim 0 50 | sox -p out.wav trim 0 10 : newfile : restart
```

The `-p` option is shorthand for `-t sox -`, i.e. write to stdout/read from stdin using SoX’s internal format.

In this particular case, you could also unroll the `restart` loop and do it in one invocation, like this:

```
rec out.wav trim 0 10 : newfile : trim 0 10 : newfile : trim 0 10 : newfile : trim 0 10 : newfile : trim 0 10
```

That’s not always possible, of course.